# Kohana 3 download file from another server

Tags: php, apache2, download, kohana-3

I am using Kohana 3. Up to now my downloadable files were residing in my application document root. So far using `$this->request->send_file($download_file);` it was working perfectly right.

But now my downloadable files are on another server can be accessed using http say http:://www.test.com/download/test1.doc. So Kohana's $this->request->send_file is no more working.

Can anybody tell me what could be alternate solution?

Answer (score 3):

You will probably want to use `Remote::get` to download the file locally, then use `Request::send_file` to download the file.

If the server is public, you can simply redirect to the file in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->response->send_file($file);
```

worked for me ..